# How to get sorted NSArray from an NSArray that contains strings in this format "2.0.1", "2.0.09", "2.0.5"

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how to get the sorted NSArray from the NSArray that contains number string with two decimal points. Can anyone help me in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will probably find your answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072545/how-to-sort-an-array-of-nsstrings-by-the-number-contained-within-in-ascending-o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick for you:

```
NSNumberFormatter *nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
  if ([obj1 isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [obj2 isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    NSArray *obj1Components = [(NSString *)obj1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    NSArray *obj2Components = [(NSString *)obj2 componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

    int highestCount = obj1Components.count;
    if (obj2Components.count > highestCount) {
        highestCount = obj2Components.count;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < highestCount; i++) {

        // If the component does not exist, just make it 0
        NSNumber *num1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
        if (i < obj1Components.count) {
            num1 = [nf numberFromString:[obj1Components objectAtIndex:i]];
        }

        NSNumber *num2 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
        if (i < obj2Components.count) {
            num2 = [nf numberFromString:[obj2Components objectAtIndex:i]];
        }

        int int1 = [num1 intValue];
        int int2 = [num2 intValue];

        if (int1 > int2) {
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        } else if (int2 > int1) {
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        }
    }

    // If we reach here, they're the same.
    return NSOrderedSame;

  } else {
      // They're not strings, so just say they're the same
      return NSOrderedSame;
  }
}];

[nf release];
```

It'll take something like ["1.4.2", "0.4.9", "1", "3.3.3.3.3"] and turn it into ["0.4.9", "1", "1.4.2", "3.3.3.3.3"]

Comment: Thank you so much it worked fine. can i get the values in descending order. Please can you get me back if you see this....

Comment: To do it in descending order, just swap the `NSOrderedDescending` and `NSOrderedAscending`.

Comment: Thanks alot it is working. I am in a hurry that we need to submit the project for testing. blindly i used your code even with out seeing it. Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 1):

I think `NSNumericSearch` is your friend. Have a look at **Sorting Strings like Finder** at  [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/SearchingStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000149-CJBBGBAI) for an example.